# How do I correct my Makefile so that it builds all my source files? (Answer: check for hidden tabs)

Tags: c, makefile, clang

In OS X v10.10.5 using clang v7.0.2 and make v3.81, I am having some problems with what I thought to be a straight-forward Makefile on a current project.

The problem developed when I added one more .h/.c pair of files--everything seemed to be working fine prior. Now make will not 'pick up' and build the new source even though I can build it manually with success. Make seems to think that the .o file is up to date even though it does not appear to even exist.

Here is a dump of my relevant project directories for reference:

```
$ ls -R
.:
LICENSE  Makefile  README.md  docs  include  src

./docs:
ptscheme.ebnf

./include:
lispbool.h  lispchar.h  lisperr.h  lispint.h  lisppair.h  lispstr.h memmanager.h  ptscheme.h

./src:
lispbool.c  lispchar.c  lisperr.c  lispint.c  lisppair.c  lispstr.c  memmanager.c  ptscheme.c
```

And, here are the contents of my Makefile:

```
$ cat Makefile
# Basic Makefile for ptscheme

# Set our paths to traditional locations for files:
#      ./src - c source files
#      ./include - c header files

vpath %.c src
vpath %.h include

CC = clang
CPPFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -g -I include
objects = ptscheme.o memmanager.o lispbool.o lispchar.o lispint.o \
          lispstr.o lisperr.o lisppair.o

all: ptscheme

ptscheme: $(objects)
    clang $(CPPFLAGS) -o ptscheme $(objects)

ptscheme.o: ptscheme.h memmanager.h

memmanager.o: ptscheme.h memmanager.h

lispbool.o: ptscheme.h memmanager.h lispbool.h

lispchar.o: ptscheme.h memmanager.h lispchar.h

lispint.o: ptscheme.h memmanager.h lispint.h

lispstr.o: ptscheme.h memmanager.h lispstr.h

lisperr.o: ptscheme.h memmanager.h lisperr.h

lisppair.o: ptscheme.h memmanager.h lisppair.h

# clean - Implement standard 'clean' target to clean up after ourselves

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f ptscheme $(objects)
```

Here is what happens when I attempt to run make:

```
   $ make
   clang  -std=c99 -Wall -g -I include  -c -o ptscheme.o src/ptscheme.c
   clang  -std=c99 -Wall -g -I include  -c -o memmanager.o src/memmanager.c
   clang  -std=c99 -Wall -g -I include  -c -o lispbool.o src/lispbool.c
   clang  -std=c99 -Wall -g -I include  -c -o lispchar.o src/lispchar.c
   clang  -std=c99 -Wall -g -I include  -c -o lispint.o src/lispint.c
   clang  -std=c99 -Wall -g -I include  -c -o lispstr.o src/lispstr.c
   clang  -std=c99 -Wall -g -I include  -c -o lisperr.o src/lisperr.c
   clang   ptscheme.o memmanager.o lispbool.o lispchar.o lispint.o lispstr.o lisperr.o lisppair.o   -o ptscheme
   clang: error: no such file or directory: 'lisppair.o'
   make: *** [ptscheme] Error 1
```

Obviously, lisppair.o is not being built even though I have an entry for it in my Makefile that follows an identical pattern as the others.

Here is a directory validating the file is missing:

```
$ ls -al *.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 ptdecker  4392 Dec 22 22:00 lispbool.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 ptdecker  3360 Dec 22 22:00 lispchar.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 ptdecker  3376 Dec 22 22:00 lisperr.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 ptdecker  3344 Dec 22 22:00 lispint.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 ptdecker  3776 Dec 22 22:00 lispstr.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 ptdecker  3244 Dec 22 22:00 memmanager.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 ptdecker 15324 Dec 22 22:00 ptscheme.o
```

When I try to have make run just the lisppair.o receipt, make tells me it thinks the object file I want is up to date (!?):

```
$ make lisppair.o
make: `lisppair.o' is up to date.
```

I can compile it manually:

```
$ clang -std=c99 -Wall -g -I include -c -o lisppair.o src/lisppair.c
```

Which produces the object file:

```
$ ls -al *.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 ptdecker  4392 Dec 22 22:00 lispbool.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 ptdecker  3360 Dec 22 22:00 lispchar.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 ptdecker  3376 Dec 22 22:00 lisperr.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 ptdecker  3344 Dec 22 22:00 lispint.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 ptdecker  5664 Dec 22 22:03 lisppair.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 ptdecker  3776 Dec 22 22:00 lispstr.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 ptdecker  3244 Dec 22 22:00 memmanager.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 ptdecker 15324 Dec 22 22:00 ptscheme.o
```

Letting me then re-run make so my final build and linking completes:

```
$ make
clang   ptscheme.o memmanager.o lispbool.o lispchar.o lispint.o lispstr.o lisperr.o lisppair.o   -o ptscheme
```

Getting me ultimately to where I want to be:

```
$ ./ptscheme
>
```

I appreciate your help and feedback!  Obviously, I'm missing something fundamental.

The complete source for all this can be found [in my github repository](https://github.com/ptdecker/ptscheme/tree/pairs).

Comment: wow, that's a tough one. did you try `make -n -d lisppair.o`, after removing it?

Comment: dawsonc623: there's an implicit rule.

Comment: kaylum figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is only evident if you look at the original `Makefile` in github. There is an errant tab on line 37 (the line after the `# clean` comment). Remove that tab and you should be good to go.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say.  What an amazing thing.  I felt like such a dummy.  Thanks for catching that and all I can say is thank goodness I thought to post the link to the source in github.

Comment: How did you see that on github? Were you using just the source viewer or did you have a tool that highlighted whitespace variances?

Comment: Firstly, in my experience, strange Makefile problems are often caused by extra or missing tabs (great idea that was to make an invisible character so important! :-) So I had an idea what I was looking for. Then the trick is just to select all the text in the browser (with the mouse or Ctrl-a) and that will show up all whitespaces.

Comment: I turn on visible whitespace in all my code editors now .. I wish everyone did so that they don't leave messy tab/spaces intermixing or trailing whitespace about the place :(